# ResultSet.beforeFirst() gets ignored in Java

Tags: java, resultset, defaulttablemodel

I would like to create `DefaultTableModel` from `ResultSet`. To do that, I need `Object[][]`.

For that, I have to specify the `size` of the object before I iterate through the table: I go to the `rs.last()`, then `rs.getRow()`, then `rs.beforeFirst()`;
After that, the `rs.next()` does not executes in the `while` cycle.
What am I doing wrong?

```
public static DefaultTableModel buildTableModel(ResultSet _resultSet) {
    ResultSetMetaData metaData;
    Object[] columnNames = null;
    Object[][] tableData = null;
    int columnCount;
    int currentRowNumber = 0;

    try {
        metaData = _resultSet.getMetaData();
        columnCount = metaData.getColumnCount();
        columnNames = new Object[columnCount];

        _resultSet.last();
        tableData = new Object[_resultSet.getRow()][columnCount];
        _resultSet.beforeFirst();

        for (int currentColumn = 0; currentColumn <= columnCount; currentColumn++) {
            columnNames[currentColumn] = metaData.getColumnName(currentColumn + 1);
        }

        while (_resultSet.next()) {
            for (int columnIndex = 0; columnIndex <= columnCount; columnIndex++) {
                tableData[currentRowNumber][columnIndex] = _resultSet.getObject(columnIndex + 1);
            }

            currentRowNumber++;
        }
    } catch (SQLException ex) {
        System.out.println("bad");
    }

    return new DefaultTableModel(tableData, columnNames);

}
```

Comment: does this not display "bad" after the SQLException is thrown? It is indicated to at least call `ex.printStackTrace()` in the `catch` block. The Exception has valuable information to debug your program, do not hide it!

Comment: I found it: This has nothing to do with `RS` or `beforeFirst()`. The problem was the `<=` in the `for` cycle, because column numbering does not start from `0`. It starts from `1`.

Comment: it should have thrown an exception anyway... don't ignore them!

Answer (score 2):

Probably your `ResultSet` is not scroll insensitive, that is, it can only be traversed forward.
See the documentation [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSet.html):

> [...] A default ResultSet object is not updatable and has a cursor that moves forward only. Thus, you can iterate through it only once and only from the first row to the last row.  [...]

To create a *bi-directional* one, do something like:

```
Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(...);
Statement stmt = conn.createStatement(ResultSet.TYPE_SCROLL_INSENSITIVE, ...);
ResultSet rset = stmt.executeQuery(sql);
```

Answer (score 1):

At first you need to print column name from `ResultSetMetaData`. Than you apply  `_resultSet.last();` and `_resultSet.beforeFirst();`. This way it has been working my machine.

```
public static DefaultTableModel buildTableModel(ResultSet _resultSet) {
    ResultSetMetaData metaData;
    Object[] columnNames = null;
    Object[][] tableData = null;
    int columnCount;
    int currentRowNumber = 0;

    try {
        metaData = _resultSet.getMetaData();
        columnCount = metaData.getColumnCount();
        columnNames = new Object[columnCount];
        // Print column here.
        for (int currentColumn = 0; currentColumn <= columnCount; currentColumn++) {
            columnNames[currentColumn] = metaData.getColumnName(currentColumn + 1);
        }
        tableData = new Object[_resultSet.getRow()][columnCount];

        //Here point resultSet cursor to last and beforeFirst.
        _resultSet.last();

        _resultSet.beforeFirst();

        // After swaping the above part. Now it will enter on while loop.
        while (_resultSet.next()) {
            for (int columnIndex = 0; columnIndex <= columnCount; columnIndex++) {
                tableData[currentRowNumber][columnIndex] = _resultSet.getObject(columnIndex + 1);
            }

            currentRowNumber++;
        }
    } catch (SQLException ex) {
        System.out.println("bad");
    }

    return new DefaultTableModel(tableData, columnNames);

}
```